# What is no trade equilibrium?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A tariff moves the economy closer to the no-trade equilibrium and, like most taxes, has deadweight losses.

Comment: It is "no-trade equilibrium", hyphenated modifier, the equilibrium of no trade, the balance that results from the absence of trade.  It is a figurative usage, since that which does not exist cannot be in balance. But at least there is no trade imbalance. Instead of *equilibrium* the author might have used the word *stasis*.

Comment: Isn't this more of an Economics question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're talking about tariffs, "economy" here probably refers to the economy of a particular country (or region, perhaps; for example, the European Union). Tariffs are typically set by governments, not individual companies.

So if the economy is that of a country, then a no-trade equilibrium likely refers to not having any imports or exports. An economy in a no-trade equilibrium would produce everything it needs itself, rather than trading with other economies.

In economic terms,

- if country A can produce product X cheaply and quickly, but produces product Y more slowly and expensively, and
- country B can produce product Y cheaply and quickly, but produces product X more slowly and expensively

given that both countries A and B need products X and Y, it's more **[efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_efficiency)** for both of them to specialize in one product and trade with each other than for each of them to make both X and Y themselves.

If country A would impose tariffs on exporting X and/or importing Y, then that would increase the cost of those products. An export tariff would disincentivize A's own people from selling X to country B, and an import tariff would disincentivize country B from selling Y to country A.

That's why adding tariffs would move country A's economy closer to a no-trade equilibrium: the higher the tariffs, the less trading there will be. (Maybe some companies could afford to produce X with the added costs of tariffs and still profit, but others might no longer turn a profit if a tariff was added.) Eventually, if the tariffs got to the point where X was just as expensive as Y, country A wouldn't bother to trade at all.

Tariffs come with a **[deadweight loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadweight_loss)** because adding them makes things more inefficient than simply trading would be. (But a country may decide to impose them anyway because it has some other objective that it's willing to give up efficiency to meet.)